# PhD in CS after 4 year bachelors in ECE + 1 year CS masters

Tags: phd, computer-science

I hold a 4 year Bachelor in Electronics and Communication Engineering and will be enrolling in a 1 year Msc in Computer Science. Will I be eligible for PhD in CS anywhere?

Comment: Where is this? What country?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re asking whether *there exists* a CS graduate program that’s likely to accept you, then probably yes. If you’re asking about top x% program in country Y, it starts to get complicated. I’d say that a lot depends on the quality of your masters work, in particular your publications (if any), your grades, your alma mater’s prestige, and last but not least - your reference letters.

Good luck!